# Prevent soft keyboard to shows up with edittext in flutter

Tags: android, flutter, android-softkeyboard, barcode-scanner

I'm trying to use an android device that has an integrated barcode scanner. I have an textfield that is filled with the data read by the scanner. It's working bu everytime I change the focus, the soft keyboard shows up and I don't know how to hide it.
This is my code:

```
    import 'dart:io';

import 'package:flutter/foundation.dart';
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:flutter/services.dart';

import 'libr.dart';

void main() {
  runApp(const MyApp());
}

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  const MyApp({super.key});

  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return MaterialApp(
      title: 'TEST',
      theme: ThemeData(
        colorScheme: ColorScheme.fromSeed(seedColor: Colors.orange),
        useMaterial3: true,
      ),
      home: const MyHomePage(),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  const MyHomePage({super.key});

  @override
  State<MyHomePage> createState() => _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _controller = TextEditingController();

  late FocusNode _focusNode;
  String _message = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _focusNode = FocusNode();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_focusNode);
    });
    _focusNode.addListener(() {
      print('1:  ${_focusNode.hasFocus}');
      if (!_focusNode.hasFocus) {
        print('request!');
        _focusNode.requestFocus();
        print('requested');
      }
      SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.hide');
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
        appBar: AppBar(
          backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
          title: Text("TEST"),
        ),
        body: Center(
          child: Padding(
            padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
            child: Stack(
              children: [
                TextField(
                  // keyboardType: TextInputType.none,
                  focusNode: _focusNode,
                  controller: _controller,
                  onChanged: (v) {
                    _message = v;
                    _controller.text = '';
                    setState(() {});
                  },
                ),
                // Container(
                //   color: Colors.white,
                //   width: double.infinity,
                //   height: double.infinity,
                // ),
                Text(_message),
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ));
  }
}
```

I try to solve it by setting the textfield read-only or setting the input type to none, but both didn't work.

Right now, every time I hide the keyboard, the focus changes and the the keyboard appear again... I'm stuck in a loop.

**Edit**
Also, the ultimate goal is to hide the text field somehow... Maybe with a stack view and a container full screen above it.

Comment: I didn't find another way to read what the reader is sending to the app. I tried with a keyboard listener without results.

Answer (score 1):

Please try the following things hope you will get the solution

1. Add this in the decoration of textfield
   decoration: InputDecoration(
   counter: Offstage(), // Hide the counter widget
   ),
2. textInputAction: TextInputAction.none
3. You can add this in the initstate of the page
   FocusScope.of(context).unfocus();
4. readOnly: true,

Comment: Thanks, but it seems not to work, the text field is not being filled

Answer (score 0):

To prevent the soft keyboard from appearing when the focus changes in your Flutter app, you can use the `TextInput.hide` method provided by the `SystemChannels.textInput` channel. You already have this method called in your `_focusNode.addListener` function, but it seems it's not working as expected.

Here's the updated `_focusNode.addListener` function where you can ensure the keyboard is hidden when the focus changes:

```
_focusNode.addListener(() {
  if (!_focusNode.hasFocus) {
    SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.hide');
  }
});
```

Make sure you remove the unnecessary requestFocus() calls in your `_focusNode.addListener` function, as they can cause unexpected behavior.

Your updated `_MyHomePageState` class should look like this:

```
class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  final _controller = TextEditingController();
  late FocusNode _focusNode;
  String _message = '';

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _focusNode = FocusNode();
    WidgetsBinding.instance!.addPostFrameCallback((_) async {
      FocusScope.of(context).requestFocus(_focusNode);
    });
    _focusNode.addListener(() {
      if (!_focusNode.hasFocus) {
        SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.hide');
      }
    });
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      appBar: AppBar(
        backgroundColor: Theme.of(context).colorScheme.inversePrimary,
        title: Text("TEST"),
      ),
      body: Center(
        child: Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: Stack(
            children: [
              TextField(
                focusNode: _focusNode,
                controller: _controller,
                onChanged: (v) {
                  _message = v;
                  _controller.text = '';
                  setState(() {});
                },
              ),
              Text(_message),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

With this change, the soft keyboard should no longer appear when the focus changes in your app.

Comment: Thanks, but what if I want to focus again the textfield?

Comment: When do you want to focus again? If the text field is filled with data from QR!
Could you give me a more detailed scenario?

Comment: I Need to do some computations and maybe the text field must be filled again after. The problem is that I need to hide the text field (the customer doesn't want to see it)

Comment: Click again for getting back the focus and on on chan get call the method
  SystemChannels.textInput.invokeMethod('TextInput.hide');
This is working.